# How can we motivate Microsoft to release a native esperanto keyboard layout for Windows?

Tags: technology, diacritics, writing

Has someone tried it, e.g. using a petition? What was the result?

I am not interested in any additional software. Just a native keyboard layout for Windows.

Comment: Interesting question. I haven't dug into this kind of things (being a software engineer) but it shouldn't be too hard for someone (that has the proper experience/knowledge) to create a keyboard layout that people can install on the system. That was the case of the Phonetic layout for Bulgarian, which later became part of the standard Windows installation alongside the BDS layout. I suppose it became popular enough and someone convinced Microsoft to add it but I do not really know. Maybe that could be a possible path for Esperanto too.

Comment: You can define your own keyboard layout with the official [Microsoft Keyboard Layout Creator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/globalization/keyboardlayouts).

Answer (score 1):

To "carry weight", I think that such a suggestion should be carried forward to Microsoft through, eg, the UEA - after all, Esperanto is a UNESCO-approved language, so they would have very little valid ammunition against.

Same problem exist with Apple, btw - on your iPad you may install native languages with 10,000 users, but Esperanto?

Answer (score 1):

In the long run, convincing Microsoft to include it has one huge problem.  If they do that, then they end up supporting it.  They may not want to dedicate resources to that.  A better approach would probably be to create a custom keyboard as grooveplex suggested and then get that into the Windows App Store.  It won't be standard and pre-installed, but it will be easy to find.  That's the approach that has been available for Linux and Android for quite a while.

Comment: Now we only need to pressure Microsoft into releasing a third-party keyboard API for Windows 10, since it doesn't exist. Sure, you can use the Keyboard Layout Creator, but that only works on desktop, not mobile, and messes up the touch keyboard on 2-in-1s.